# Stack rows under one another

Tags: r, dataframe, stack, rows

My dataset looks like this

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 AA   BB   NA
 DD   EE   NA
 FF   NA   GG
```

I would like to stack rows under one another so that the final product looks like this

```
Col1
AA
BB
DD
EE
FF
GG
```

I really struggle finding an easy way to do this. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
data.frame(col1 = na.omit(c(t(dat))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  col1
#1   AA
#2   BB
#3   DD
#4   EE
#5   FF
#6   GG
```

We first transpose your data using `t()` which returns a matrix, then we call `c()` to get vector, remove `NA`s with `na.omit` and finally create desired output using `data.frame()`.

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(Col1 = c("AA", "DD", "FF"), Col2 = c("BB", "EE", 
NA), Col3 = c(NA, NA, "GG")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you so much! I did not think it was possible in only one line of code!